# open a new tab using MVC Razor @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Am trying to work out how to open a tab when i click a link.

Here is my link which am trying to open, i have set it as this, but as you can see i have added target = "_blank" which does not open in a new tab.

```
  <div data-callno='@parts.Call_Num' data-url="@Url.Action("GetCallInfo", "CallHandling" , new {target = "_blank"})">
  <div class="callViewSubmit toolbarIcon"></div>
  Test </div>
```

This opens on the same page, after looking at google i noticed am using URL.ACTION and not HTML.ACTIONLINK.

as a test i tried this on the page, and it did open in a new tab:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("New report", "New", "Report", null, new {target = "_blank"})
```

Any ideas how i can open my div in a new tab using the Url.Action way.

> //New

This is the javascript i used to open the link, would i able to open the link in javascript rather than url.action

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.callViewSubmit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).parent().data("url"),
            data: { callNumber: $(this).parent().data("callno") },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#CallDetail").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are needing to open the URL in a new tab/window, then AJAX is not the correct way to go.  You can still open a new tab/window from javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.callViewSubmit').click(function () {
        window.open($(this).parent().data("url"));
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is am calling a paramater 'callNumber' to be passed to the data, but with the window.open it just opens the parent data, whereas before i used:                data: { callNumber: $(this).parent().data("callno") },

Comment: @mali - Then you need to make it part of your Url to begin with if it is a parameter to the action method you are hitting on your controller.  `@Url.Action("GetCallInfo", "CallHandling" , new {callNumber = parts.Call_Num})`.  Now, it is part of the Url itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're assigning this in a `data-*` attribute (and only thing you can modify is the URI, there's nothing you can do to accomplish the behavior. This would need to be changed in the piece of code accessing `data-url` (and how it handles it).

Comment: i need the data-url as the page i want to open must show the data. is there a way to do it in the razor view

Comment: The only way you can control _how_ it opens it with `target` attribute on the `<a>` (or javascript handing the url). If all you have to work with is the URL, it can't be done.

Comment: iv posted the javascript for the the data, is there any chance i can use the javascript to open it on a new tab

Comment: how would i make this open on a new tab, what will be the best way for me now.

Comment: Seconding @BradChristie. If you want the result of the AJAX to open in a new tab, there's no point to having it be done via AJAX. Just have a regular old link with target="_blank". The only purpose of AJAX is to bring additional data into the *existing* page from the server. In general, it doesn't seem like you really understand any of the concepts you're dealing with here. I suggest you step back and do a little more study.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
    Url.RouteUrl("routeName",
new
{
  controller = "controllerName",
  action = "ActionName",
  callNumber: "Value"
});
```

*Then create link:*

```
var link =
                                        "<a data-original-title=\"title\" target='_top' data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" " +
                                        "href=\"" + viewLink +
                                        "\" data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"GET\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" " +
                                        "data-ajax-update=\"#CallDetail\" >" + This is link;
```